# "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" on Ubuntu 18.04 Lenovo Thinkpad T470

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo

On clicking the Wifi settings, its showing "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found".
I referred many pages and tried the steps to install the Github drivers, but no luck.
Please refer below the details of system :

**Kernel Version :**

```
uname -r
5.0.0-1068-oem-osp1
```

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
 network DISABLED        
 description: Ethernet interface
 product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
 vendor: Intel Corporation
 physical id: 0
 bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
 logical name: wlp4s0
 version: 78
 serial: 88:b1:11:8e:4b:58
 width: 64 bits
 clock: 33MHz
 capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
 configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-1068-oem-osp1 firmware=36.9f0a2d68.0 8265-36.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
 resources: irq:131 memory:ec100000-ec101fff
```

**iwconfig**

```
enp0s20f0u1  no wireless extensions.

br-0e356c40caa2  no wireless extensions.

br-94a21bdbaaa2  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

br-d00350344258  no wireless extensions.

cscotun0  no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    no wireless extensions.
```

Can someone please help on this urgently? Please let me know if I need to provide more details.

Also, I am getting a pop-up from the past few days of upgrading to **Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS**. Hence want to check if **upgrading** might solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few articles online about people having trouble with WiFi on the Thinkpad T470 and Ubuntu 18.04. While there are solutions available if you're willing to install specific kernels, upgrading to 20.04.1 should resolve the issue for you.

Comment: Thanks. Will try upgrading to 20.04.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my hp laptop. I followed this [link](https://medium.com/@siddhesh.m/fix-no-wifi-adapter-found-for-hp-laptops-with-ubuntu-18-04-9ea509523841) and it solved my problem, also check the network driver in the bios menu, which may be turned of weird reasons. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes I had referred this page. But on github, now the "rtlwifi_new" driver does not exist. I tried with its equivalent like rtw88 and rtl8723bu, but it did not work. Also in the BIOS, the network driver is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. The issue got resolved after updating installed packages to latest version.

**sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade -y**